# Ansible shell and with_items

Tags: shell, ansible

I would like to know if

```
  - shell: >
            hostname;
            whoami;
```

and

```
  - shell: "{{item}}"
    with_items: ['hostname', 'whoami']
```

are equivalent? In the second example, Ansible will **always** use the same SSH connection for both commands (hostname, whoami)?

---

It seems to me that it is false...

```
  - shell: "{{item}}"
    with_items: ['export miavar=PIPPO', 'echo $miavar']

    (item=export miavar=PIPPO) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "export miavar=PIPPO", "stdout": ""}
    (item=echo $miavar)        => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo $miavar", "stdout": ""}
```

--ansible 2.1.1.0

Riccardo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ansible runs each loop iteration as separate run, so you end up with different ssh sessions.

There are some exceptions described in [ANSIBLE_SQUASH_ACTIONS](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/constants.py#L238) variable:

```
"apk, apt, dnf, package, pacman, pkgng, yum, zypper"
```

This modules are smart enough to squash all items into a single task call.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer, with_items makes ansible run separate loop iterations. One more benefit of this is debuggability esp. if a lot of commands are chained under one shell task. For eg: For the above, ansible will internally run it as:

```
- shell: "{{item}}"
    with_items: ['hostname', 'whoami']
```

is equivalent to:

```
- shell: 'hostname:

- shell: 'whoami'
```

Since its broken into two separate tasks, if one of them fails, ansible will point to the exact failing task (command) instead of the whole chain in the alternative.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add a list of commands to a variable and substitute the variable in the place where you need to execute them.

```
vars:
  shell_cmd:
    - "hostname &&"
    - whoami
tasks:
  - shell: "{{shell_cmd}}"
```

Enjoy!